# How to combine multiple rows from the same column that have the same data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

The code I have is:

```
SELECT datepart(year, request_created_date) AS request_year,
    datepart(month, request_created_date) AS request_month,
    datepart(week, request_created_date) AS request_week,
    count(request_id) AS request_count
FROM nyc311_requests
GROUP BY request_created_date
ORDER BY request_week
```

In the output I'm getting, I have two rows where request_week is 36 and 7 rows where it's 37. What I want is to combine columns like that into one row.

Comment: Have you tried changing your GROUP BY to `GROUP BY datepart(week, request_created_date)`

Comment: Yes, but I get an error saying that request_created_date is invalid because it's not an aggregate or in a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: How about the following: `GROUP BY datepart(year, request_created_date), datepart(month, request_created_date), datepart(week, request_created_date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use a GROUP BY clause, you are going to have to include all the fields in other than the calculated field in the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT datepart(year, request_created_date) AS request_year,
    datepart(month, request_created_date) AS request_month,
    datepart(week, request_created_date) AS request_week,
    count(request_id) AS request_count
FROM nyc311_requests
GROUP BY datepart(year, request_created_date),
    datepart(month, request_created_date),
    datepart(week, request_created_date)
ORDER BY request_week
```

Or, if you want a cleaner looking query:

```
SELECT M.*, count(*) AS request_count FROM 
(
  SELECT datepart(year, request_created_date) AS request_year,
         datepart(month, request_created_date) AS request_month,
         datepart(week, request_created_date) AS request_week
  FROM nyc311_requests
)AS M
GROUP BY M.request_year, M.request_month, M.request_week
ORDER BY M.request_week
```